# Changes to UIButton Does Not Update Cell Until Scrolled

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uibutton

I solved this using UIButtonState (duhz), but I am curious why *exactly* this did not work in the first place.

I defined the "normal" icons in the storyboard, then configured it to show the "highlighted" icon when the object is set. However, when the table first loaded, I did not see the updated icon.

But after the table was scrolled, the highlighted icons showed up. What is happening here?

```
class TweetCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tweetLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeStampLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var favButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var replyButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var retweetButton: UIButton!

    var tweet: Tweet!{
        didSet {
            profileImage.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:tweet.user.profile_image_url))
            nameLabel.text = tweet.user.name
            tweetLabel.text = tweet.text

            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm"
            let str = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(tweet.createdAt)
            timeStampLabel.text = str

            if (tweet.favorited) {
                favButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "star_highlighted.png")
            } else {

            }

            if (tweet.retweeted) {
                retweetButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "retweet_highlighted.png")
            } else {

            }

        }
    }
```

// Before Scrolling
[image]

// After Scrolling
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the tableview is reusing cells which have the highlighted image view. To solve this issue you need to set the unhighlighted image in the else section.

```
if (tweet.favorited) {
                favButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "star_highlighted.png")
            } else {
    favButton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "star_unhighlighted.png")
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure for cause but you can use this to fix,I know you already fix it but still posting the way to fix this issue.

```
[cell performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```